# How should I interpret this DP3T switch diagram?

Tags: switches, schematics

Which pins are the poles and how are they connected in the three positions of the following switch?

[Datasheet for DP3T Switch](https://www.cuidevices.com/product/resource/digikeypdf/slw-993515-2a-smt-tr.pdf) (SLW-993515-2A-SMT-TR).

I'm just not sure how to read this schematic:

[image: Schematic from DP3T switch datasheet]

[image: Photo of switch]

[image: Dimensions and pinout of switch]

Comment: The spacing on the pins would suggest perhaps that 4/8 are the poles and 1-3/5-7 are the throws, but the "schematic" is unclear, making it appear as though 2/6 are unused. I presume you don't have a physical switch and can just measure continuity?

Comment: @JYelton Not yet, just ordered a few and am waiting on them, was just hoping to get a jump start on designing before they arrived.  Glad I'm not alone in thinking the schematic is unclear!

Comment: @JYelton  How can two pins be unused, if this is a triple-throw switch?

Comment: @MikeB They can't. My thought was they might have included the wrong drawing in the datasheet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hard to know why they wouldn't make this information very clear. From experience several decades ago I would think it's something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxvbbc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- A: 3 to 1.
- B: 3 to 2.
- C: 3 to 4.

This is very simple to manufacture.

Non-shorting means that the contacts are break-before-make so 1, 2 and 4 should never be connected while the switch is in transition.

Comment: Of course with this switch having a "Double Pole" format there is a similar switching sequence repeated on the opposite side with pin 7 being the common pole, and positions A,B,C making connections as:   7 to 5,    7 to 6,   7 to 8.